# Averaging all measure values in Tableau 2019

Tags: average, tableau-api

I would like to do averaging for all the measure values in Tableau.

How can I do this in Tableau 2019?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I hv 50 over measure names. I want to use those measure name as filter to do the analysis on the dashboard. However, I like to use average value of all measure. On dashboard I cannot change the aggregation of measure values. So I need to go back to the sheet to change to average. Then, I will disappear when I switch to another measure name. To solve this, I want to create by default all measure value is average

Answer (score 0):

The following answer from the Tableau forums should resolve your issue.

"I found if I select everything in Measures (from the data connection), then right click > Default Properties > Aggregation > Average  it works when I use the Measures Values."

https://community.tableau.com/thread/157029

The individual change for one measure can be seen here visually.

https://www.thedataschool.co.uk/natalia-miteva/tableautiptuesday-how-to-change-the-default-aggregation-for-a-measure/